# What do you call the soil that are used to plant other large plants and surrounded by grass in a garden

Tags: word-request

[image]

Is there a specific term for this or do we just use the word soil?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would call it a "bed". That is often preceded by "flower", suggesting that the soil in question is used for annual and perennial flowers. But I've frequently heard it used without the "flower" qualifier to refer to areas of soil used for shrubs.

Another option, if the soil is at the edge of an area of grass, is "border".

Both "bed" and "border" can be used in singular form or, by adding an "s" in plural.